# WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated/SafeAccessTokenHandle on Task/different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

On a .NET 6 web api I've created an AuthorizedUser which executes methods with `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated`. In this case, the class is being used by a FileReaderWriterClass.

```cs
public class AuthorizedUser : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SafeAccessTokenHandle safeAccessTokenHandle;

    public AuthorizedUser(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        string domain = configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthorizedUser:Domain");
        string username = configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthorizedUser:Username");
        string password = configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthorizedUser:Password");

        safeAccessTokenHandle = SafeAccessTokenHandle(domain, username, password);
    }

    private static SafeAccessTokenHandle SafeAccessTokenHandle(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        bool loginSucces = LogonUser(username, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out SafeAccessTokenHandle safeAccessTokenHandle);

        if (!loginSucces)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unsuccesful login at SafeAccessTokenHandle()");
        }

        return safeAccessTokenHandle;
    }

    public async Task Run(Task task)
    {
        await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync(safeAccessTokenHandle, () => task);
    }

    public TResult Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
    { 
        return WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(safeAccessTokenHandle, () => function());
    }

    public TResult Run<TArg1, TResult>(Func<TArg1, TResult> function, TArg1 arg1)
    {
        return WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(safeAccessTokenHandle, () => function(arg1));
    }
}
```

The last two methods seem to work, the first one which awaits a Task, doesn't. Getting the error

> Access to the path '\different-server\file\path.json' is denied.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safeaccesstokenhandle?view=net-6.0) states

> Provides a safe handle to a Windows thread or process access token.

Does this mean that, when executing a `Task`, it being on a different `Thread`, the SafeAccessToken won't work? Should I

1. Create a new token for a request on this task, instead using a field?
2. Execute `Task`on token-thread?
3. Don't work with Tasks (I'm using `File.WriteAllBytesAsync` which can be replaced with `File.WriteAllBytes`)?

EDIT:
The Code to retrieve a SafeAccessTokenHandle:

```cs
//source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=net-7.0
private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword,
    int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeAccessTokenHandle phToken);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run asynchronous code, you should be using the [WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonatedasync)

Comment: Thanks, gonna use that. But still thesame error (UnauthorizedAccessException).

Comment: Is the token the correct one at that time?

Comment: @JannickBreunis Please show your current code using the `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync` method

Comment: Changed it in the post. But it's only RunImpersonated changed to RunImpersonatedAsync?